# Where can I find a freebase dump that is several years old?

Tags: dataset, freebase

We can find the newest (updated weekly) dump of Freebase here:

https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

Does anyone know where I would be able to find an much older dump of Freebase? For example, one from many years back?

Comment: I know it's a very old question. Nevertheless, it would be nice if you could mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/

Just use https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/freebase-public/rdf/freebase-rdf-xxxxxxxxxxx.gz

You can find in the XML: rdf/freebase-rdf-xxxxxxxxxxx.gz...

here xxxxxxxxxxx will be like this: 2015-02-15-00-00, 2012-08-17-21-54.. etc:

Oldest we have here is : freebase-rdf-**2012-08-17**-21-54.gz